# How Do I Update Ubuntu Linux Software Using Command Line?

Tags: command-line

I'm new and I want to know how do I update Ubuntu Linux for security and application fix/upgrades using the ssh command line? How can I install updates via the command line option?

Comment: The same way you would do at the local system? There are no specific commands for doing it remotely.

Answer (score 3):

**"*how do I update Ubuntu Linux for security and application fix/upgrades?*"**

A stock install of Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server will handle deb package security upgrades automatically. The system will also handle ALL snap package upgrades automatically. No user interaction is needed.

A stock install of Ubuntu Desktop will prompt you to install non-security deb upgrades when they are available.

Ubuntu Server lacks the desktop upgrade prompt, obviously. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto for details on how to use the `apt` application to install/remove/upgrade deb packages.

Comment: I thank you very much for your answer

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question about CLI commands?

Comment: @heynnema seems like the OP's vague question can be interpreted many ways.

Answer (score 1):

The basic CLI commands to use locally, or over SSH, would be...

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt upgrade`

`reboot` # if required